# How to create a temp file with a specific name

Tags: php, file, filenames, temp

I would like to create a temp file which deletes itself on script ending with a specific filename.

I know `tmpfile()` does the "autodelete" function but it doesn't let you name the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about this: don't care what the filename is. Or, create a non-temp file by name and delete it yourself.

Comment: why do you need to have a specific file name ?

Comment: @Drew If I didn't care about the filename, I wouldn't be asking it in the first place...

Comment: @mmm Because it needs to be a unique file inside a folder in another server

Comment: @John It seems there is no way to make this, have you tried making file with `tmpfile()` and copying this as `(tmpfile(), '/foo')`

Comment: @samaYo yeah. I tried it. It "works" but only after the script ending

Comment: @Drew But the question I'm asking is WHY there isn't a way to do this properly?

Comment: @Drew I don't know when it's ending the script

Comment: @Drew The file needs to be deleted as soon as the script ends. I don't want to do it with cron

Comment: @Drew Sorry, Maverick gave a posible solution. I think I'll keep it. If you have any other idea I would like to know it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to create a unique filename you can use tempnam().

This is an example:

```
<?php
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "FOO");

$handle = fopen($tmpfile, "w");
fwrite($handle, "writing to tempfile");
fclose($handle);

unlink($tmpfile);
```

**UPDATE 1**

temporary file class manager

```
<?php
class TempFile
{
    public $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Phrappe');
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        unlink($this->path);
    }
}

function i_need_a_temp_file()
{
  $temp_file = new TempFile;
  // do something with $temp_file->path
  // ...
  // the file will be deleted when this function exits
}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. The file needs to delete itself on script ending without telling it

Comment: You can create a class that manage all and delete the file in the __destructor function.

Comment: That's a feasible solution. Thanks :)

Comment: With this solution you can also create a file wherever you want and with every name you want without `tempnam()`.